# How would I import everything from a certain folder to use into Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wanting to make a discord bot so I would like my main.js file to connect to discord and import all files from a folder named "add-ons" for example I want main.js to import mod.js which hold all moderation commands without having to import them all manually and still use the functions and such, if this is possible that would be great if someone can help

Comment: Are you using Node?

Comment: yes using node sorry i didn't mention that

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use `require()`.

Comment: There's an npm module that seems to do what you're looking for: [require-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all).

Comment: ill look into it @SimpleJ

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) method which reads the content of a directory:

```
const addonDir = './addons/';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
var loadedAddons = {};
fs.readdir(addonDir, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    //either simply
    require(path.join(addonDir, file));
    //*OR* provide a contract for loading/unloading which allows hot loading of code
    loadedAddons[file] = require(path.join(addonDir, file)).load();
  });
})
```

Comment: thank you for the response I get an error with this saying Cannot find module mod.js

Comment: `require` needs the module's path to be spelled out. The code has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Node.js, so there are a few possibilities here.

1. Create a file `addons/index.js` where you export all the other dependencies (via require), then require the `index.js` file.
2. Use the `require-all`-package
3. Write a custom loader with fs that iterates over files and requires them dynamically. Check out `fs.readdir` for this.